# how to get the response body in code webtest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, webtest

I wrote a webtest that calls a web-service.

I want to get the response body and do some validation on it.

```
    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {


        WebTestRequest request2 = new WebTestRequest("webservice");

        request2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StringHttpBody request2Body = new StringHttpBody();

        request2Body.ContentType = "application/json";
        request2Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
        request2Body.BodyString = @"{                                       <body>}";
        request2.Body = request2Body;


        WebTestResponse res = new WebTestResponse();
        console.WriteLine(res.BodyBytes);

       yield return request2;

       request2 = null;
    }
```

When i ran the above code i didn't get any response on my console.

How can i get the response body using coded webtest?

Comment: The same question has been asked on the Microsoft forums, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/944dc265-99d3-41a7-916a-2737e0555e58/how-to-get-the-response-body-in-code-webtest?forum=vstest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three problems with the code in the question

1. The code in the question does not perform the request before doing the `WriteLine`. The two statements `WebTestResponse res = new WebTestResponse();` and `console.WriteLine(res.BodyBytes);` just create a new `WebTestResponse` object (with all default values) and then try to print part of its contents. The request is issued by the code that calls your `GetRequestEnumerator` method.
2. The `console` object is not defined. The normal console has a first letter uppercase, ie `Console`.
3. When a web test executes I am not sure where its "console" output will go. The standard output of a web test is not, as far as I know, a well defined thing.

An easy way to get at the response body is to use the `PostRequest` method of a `WebTestRequestPlugin`. For a start

```
public class BodyContentsDemo : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bb = e.Response.BodyBytes;
        string ss = e.Response.BodyString;

        e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult(
            "BodyBytes is " +
            bb == null ? " null"
            : bb.Length.ToString() + " bytes");

        e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult(
            "BodyString is " +
            ss == null ? "null"
            : ss.Length.ToString() + " chars");

        // Use bb or ss.
    }
}
```

Note the use of `AddCommentToResult` to provide logging information to the web test results log.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to find a solution for last couple of days I was struggling to capture the response text from Web Performance test. Hope this helps

public override IEnumerator GetRequestEnumerator()
    {

```
    WebTestRequest request2 = new WebTestRequest("webservice");

    request2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request2.Method = "POST";
    request2.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    StringHttpBody request2Body = new StringHttpBody();

    request2Body.ContentType = "application/json";
    request2Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
    request2Body.BodyString = @"{<body>}";
    request2.Body = request2Body;


    WebTestResponse res = new WebTestResponse();
    console.WriteLine(res.BodyBytes);

   yield return request2;
   /*This will generate a new string which can be part of your filename when      you run performance tests*/
   String randomNo = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "");
   /*This will generate a new file each time your WebRequest runs so you know what the server is returning when you perform webtests*/
   /*You can use some Json parser if your response is Json and capture and validate the response*/
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\XXXX\PerformanceTestRequests\LastResponse" + randomNo+ ".txt", this.LastResponse.BodyString);
   request2 = null;
}
```